# cannot find module /srv/server.js - gcloud app engine

Tags: javascript, gcloud

The error I get when trying to deploy my service to app engine is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/srv/server.js' at 

`Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15) at 

Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25) at Function.Module.runMain 

(module.js:694:10) at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16) at 

bootstrap_node.js:625:3`
```

I dont have a /srv/server.js and why would it look for it?!?!?

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check your package.json, you should have at least:

```
"main": "app.js"
```

where app.js is your node-file which starts the server.

You could also add:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
},
```

and run "yarn start" to test that your server starts ok.

Comment: having the "start" in "script" was necessary in my case. "main" alone wasn't working.

Comment: me too. i wasted so many hours with this. im not sure why the package.json did not include this one by default.

Comment: make sure it isn't like start:prod

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by putting the App Engine deployment file in the project home:

[Home path nodejs project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48gFB.png)

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never.

The error is coming up because you are loading the relative path.

Solution:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js"
},
```